# Import csv files with leading "+" into Excel

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

How do I import csv files with international number format in one of the fields
(ex +1800-555-1234 or +180055512345) into Microsoft excel, without the "+" getting dropped, and Excel treating the entry as a real number

Answer (score 0):

Very easy

**Don't open the file by double-clicking!**

In the **Data** tab in the *get external data* section, touch **From Text**

This invokes the Data Import Wizard..................tell the Wizard that the field is *Text*